# Resources about animated splash art

Tags: flash, actionscript, effects, visual-effects

I have always been fascinated in these stuff:

- [Blizzard's "live" banners](http://eu.blizzard.com/en-gb/)
- [Riot's "live" character splash screens](http://beta.euw.leagueoflegends.com/)

Do they have a specific name I could google and teach myself the art of creating them? I have experience in graphics rendering, but I assume some far less complicated tricks are used to achieve the illusion of 3D and animation in the current examples. I also assume, that Flash is the most convenient platform to build such effects. I am not interested in actionscript tutorials, rather the specific techniques to make banners look like "3D" and "alive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week I stumbled upon an answer by a complete coincidence. Turns out there is a whole science based on such things, called [Motion Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_graphics).

A typical software, used for the creation of such things is [Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html), and the effect I was trying to achieve is called [Cinemagraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinemagraph). Therefore such designs can be achieved by following cinemagraph tutorials.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking around for this for ages! Thanks!